# Initializing an object in a class constructor

Tags: c++, class, constructor

There is a runtime error:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
> what():  std::bad_alloc Aborted (core dumped)

from the below c++ class:

```
class PoseDrawer
{
public:
  PoseDrawer() : tf_(),  target_frame_("turtle1"), tf_filter_(point_sub_, tf_, target_frame_, 10)
  {
    point_sub_.subscribe(n_, "turtle_point_stamped", 10);
    tf_filter_.registerCallback( &PoseDrawer::msgCallback, this );
  } ;


private:
  message_filters::Subscriber<geometry_msgs::PointStamped> point_sub_;
  tf::TransformListener tf_;
  tf::MessageFilter<geometry_msgs::PointStamped> tf_filter_;
  ros::NodeHandle n_;
  std::string target_frame_;

  void msgCallback(const boost::shared_ptr<const geometry_msgs::PointStamped>& point_ptr) 
  {
  //stuff
  }
};
```

It is due to the way the `tf_filter_` is initialized because if I convert `tf_filter_` to a pointer as below, it will work as expected. so what is the difference between the above and the below code?

```
class PoseDrawer
{
public:
  PoseDrawer() : tf_(),  target_frame_("turtle1")
  {
    point_sub_.subscribe(n_, "turtle_point_stamped", 10);
    tf_filter_=new tf::MessageFilter<geometry_msgs::PointStamped>(point_sub_, tf_, target_frame_, 10);
    tf_filter_->registerCallback( &PoseDrawer::msgCallback, this );
  } ;


private:
  message_filters::Subscriber<geometry_msgs::PointStamped> point_sub_;
  tf::TransformListener tf_;
  tf::MessageFilter<geometry_msgs::PointStamped>* tf_filter_;
  ros::NodeHandle n_;
  std::string target_frame_;

  void msgCallback(const boost::shared_ptr<const geometry_msgs::PointStamped>& point_ptr) 
  {
   //stuff
  };

};
```

Comment: Have tried to attach debugger? Do you know at what line it failed?

Comment: `std::bad_alloc` generally means you've run out of memory.  We don't really have enough information here to diagnose the issue.  Can you make a [mre]?

Comment: This might happen when you instantiate an object inside its own constructor directly, or indirectly when that object is instantiated in some other constructors of other objects instantiated inside your constructor. That somehow leads to direct or indirect recursion of constructor.

Comment: I edited and added the working code in the question. The issue clearly stems from the way  `tf_filter_` is instantiated inside the class.

Comment: I've gotten `std::bad_alloc`s from calling functions on dead containers. The way moving `tf_filter_` to dynamic memory and leaking it hides the issue makes me think that your `PoseDrawer` instance is unexpectedly destroyed at some point, with some other code still referring to its now-dead `tf_filter_` and later accessing it. That's just an educated guess though -- using your debugger to pinpoint exactly what code throws this exception will help a lot.

Comment: You are probably using `point_sub_` before it was initialized

Comment: @SemyonBurov thanks. so if this is the case how I can instantiate `tf_filter_` then?

Comment: @b3hn4m You can try to place `point_sub_` before in initialization list, but it might be better to move the whole thing to constructor body

Answer (score 1):

In the class you declare `target_frame_` after `tf_filter_` but you use it in `tf_filter_` constructor. You should get warnings about that. Here's distilled example of what you are doing:

```cpp
#include <string>

class PoseDrawer
{
public:
  PoseDrawer() : target_frame_("turtle1"), tf_filter_(target_frame_)
  {
  } 

private:
  std::string tf_filter_;
  std::string target_frame_;
};
```

See [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:3,endLineNumber:12,positionColumn:3,positionLineNumber:12,selectionStartColumn:3,selectionStartLineNumber:12,startColumn:3,startLineNumber:12),source:%27%23include+%3Cstring%3E%0A%0Aclass+PoseDrawer%0A%7B%0Apublic:%0A++PoseDrawer()+:+target_frame_(%22turtle1%22),+tf_filter_(target_frame_)%0A++%7B%0A++%7D+%3B%0A%0Aprivate:%0A++std::string+tf_filter_%3B%0A++std::string+target_frame_%3B%0A%7D%3B%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:gsnapshot,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-Wall%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:50,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,tree:%271%27,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

```
<source>: In constructor 'PoseDrawer::PoseDrawer()':
<source>:12:15: warning: 'PoseDrawer::target_frame_' will be initialized after [-Wreorder]
   12 |   std::string target_frame_;
      |               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:11:15: warning:   'std::string PoseDrawer::tf_filter_' [-Wreorder]
   11 |   std::string tf_filter_;
      |               ^~~~~~~~~~
<source>:6:3: warning:   when initialized here [-Wreorder]
    6 |   PoseDrawer() : target_frame_("turtle1"), tf_filter_(target_frame_)
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~
```

Move `target_frame_` declaration before `tf_filter_` and see if it helps.